# how to merge two json objects if keys are in numeric string and arrange in ascending order in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to merge two json objects if their keys are in numering string and arrange in ascending order

```js
let obj1 = {
'10' : "ten"
'2' : "two",
"30": "thirty
}


let obj2 = {
'4' : "four",
'5' : "five",
"1": "one"
}

   // output i want :

let res = {
"1": "one",
'2' : "two",
'4' : "four",
'5' : "five",
'10' : "ten"
"30": "thirty
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It seems the spread already sort the keys so you just need it

```js
let obj1 = {
  '10': "ten",
  '2': "two",
  "30": "thirty"
}


let obj2 = {
  '4': "four",
  '5': "five",
  "1": "one"
}

console.log({ ...obj1, ...obj2 })
```

**Previous answer**

Object.entries order the keys, you can then run Object.fromEntries and you have your object sorted

```js
let obj1 = {
  '10': "ten",
  '2': "two",
  "30": "thirty"
}


let obj2 = {
  '4': "four",
  '5': "five",
  "1": "one"
}

console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries({ ...obj1, ...obj2 })))
```

Comment: My pleasure, I just edit my answer, I saw that you don't need to pass by the `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries())` part

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate the key/values of `obj2` and place them into `obj1` and it will order itself.

```js
let obj1 = {
"10": "ten",
"2": "two",
"30": "thirty"
}


let obj2 = {
"4": "four",
"5": "five",
"1": "one"
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj2)) {
    obj1[key] = value;
}
console.log(obj1);
```